# Debugging nested if statement for price break deviations

Tags: ms-access

I have a nested `if` statement in order to identify `part_ID`'s that were sold below the proper unit price, for given price-break Qty  (`qb`=qty break and `up`=unit price). The query works properly for most records, but around 30% of the records, the proper price field is null when it should be populated. I assume that there must be a bug in my query. I would be super grateful if somebody could debug.  Ideally, you could give me the proper SQL for me to copy and paste.

```
SELECT tlsp.PART_ID, 
   IIf(IsNull([tlsp].[qb1]) 
           And [tlsp].[last_sell_prc_cstmr]<[tlsp].[last_sell_prc_cstmr],
       [tlsp].[last_sell_prc_cstmr],
       IIf([tlsp].[last_order_qty_by_cstmr]>=[tlsp].[qb1]
              And [tlsp].[last_order_qty_by_cstmr]<[tlsp].[qb2] 
              And [tlsp].[last_sell_prc_cstmr]<[tlsp].[up1],
           [tlsp].[up1],
           IIf([tlsp].[last_order_qty_by_cstmr]>=[tlsp].[qb2] 
                   And [tlsp].[last_order_qty_by_cstmr]<[tlsp].[qb3] 
                   And [tlsp].[last_sell_prc_cstmr]<[tlsp].[up2],
               [tlsp].[up2],
               IIf([tlsp].[last_order_qty_by_cstmr]>=[tlsp].[qb3] 
                       And [tlsp].[last_sell_prc_cstmr]<[tlsp].[up3],
                   [tlsp].[up3])))) AS [proper price]
FROM tblLastSellPriceToCustomer_tmp AS tlsp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at that, it seems like you are missing the last false part.

```
 IIf (arg, true part, false part)
```

Your statement:

```
SELECT t.PART_ID, 
       IIf(arg,true,
           IIf(arg,true,
               IIf(arg,true,
                   IIf(arg,true,MISSING FALSE)))) AS proper price
FROM tblLastSellPriceToCustomer_tmp AS tlsp;
```

I have marked the missing part `,MISSING FALSE`.

Comment: I added null for the false, to no avail. please advise

Comment: If you want to avoid nulls, I do not think null is a good choice for the false part. You need to pick a default price. It might be a good idea to pick a price that really stands out, just to check, so you might like to try `1000001` for now, for the false part.

Comment: It is not a magic number, it is debugging 'just to check' and 'for now'. The OP does not seem to know where the null values are coming from.

Comment: I'm with both of you in this one--"magic numbers" can be _very_ useful during debugging, as long as you remember to remove them....